# git reset resulting in changes to both working directory and stage

Tags: git, git-reset, working-directory, git-stage

I have a commit with many files in it.

One of the files in the commit has several changes, one of which I would like to undo.

So, I was thinking I could reset that particular file back to `HEAD~` leaving the outstanding changes I had made in the working-directory. Then, I could use `git add -p` and only stage the desired changes, followed by `git commit --amend`.

First, I made sure that I had no outstanding changes in either my working-directory or stage.

Then, I ran this command:

```
git reset HEAD~ -- path/to/file
```

But, to my surprise, `git status` now shows changes to both my working-directory and stage. Further inspection using `gitk` shows that the changes in my working-directory and stage are identical.

Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of reset:

- *does not* affect `HEAD` itself or the current branch (so it's not the same as *any* of `git reset --hard`, `git reset --mixed`, or `git reset --soft`);
- *does* affect the contents of the index;
- *does not* affect the contents of the work-tree.

Hence this:

> So, I was thinking I could reset that particular file back to `HEAD~` leaving the outstanding changes I had made in the working-directory. Then, I could use `git add -p` and only stage the desired changes, followed by `git commit --amend`.

... is a fine plan!  But as you saw, the output of `git status` becomes a bit surprising:

> `git status` now shows changes to both my working-directory and stage.

The reason is that what `git status` does includes running two `git diff`s.  If you could name the index and the work-tree as arguments to `git diff` (you can't), that might be:

- `git diff --name-status HEAD <index>`: this is "changes to be committed".
- `git diff --name-status <index> <work-tree>`: this is "changes not staged for commit".

Since the *index* version of `path/to/file` now matches the `HEAD~1` version of `path/to/file`, which is different from the `HEAD` version, the first `git diff` shows that "staged changes" exist.

Likewise, the work-tree version does not match the index version, so `git status` says that there unstaged changes also exist.

You can in fact now run `git add -p`.  Git will extract the index version to a temporary file, diff the index version against the work-tree version, and let you add changes to the index version (from the work-tree version).

#### There was a different route you could have gone

If you wish to be able to *see what you are doing*, though, it might have been better to, at the start, do a `git reset --soft HEAD~1`.  This kind of reset:

- *does* affect the current branch, using `HEAD` to find out what that branch is and adjust it;
- *does not* affect the contents of the index; and
- *does not* affect the contents of the work-tree.

You would now be in a similar position as before, but now you would need to:

```
git reset HEAD path/to/file
```

to make the index version match the `HEAD` version, now that `HEAD` names the desired commit.  The commit you made that you don't want—that you intended to `--amend`—is now "one past the end" of the branch tip:

```
             X  [bad commit, now shoved out of the way]
            /
...--o--o--@   <-- branch
```

Now `git status` makes sense, because it's comparing `@` to index instead of `X` to index.  (As before, `git status` also compares index to work-tree.)  Now you can `git add -p` as you intended, and then `git commit` without the `--amend` part.

You do not have to do it this way; you can just continue with your current plan.  If you like the `git status` result here better, though, you can convert your current plan to this other plan right now, by doing the `git reset --soft HEAD~1`.  This will change the current branch name so that it stops pointing to `X` and starts pointing to `@`, and change nothing else at all.

Comment: Superb explanation, but a question: If the conceptual `git diff --name-status <index> <work-tree>` is used for git status, how come git status doesn't _always_ show "changes not staged for commit" changes when there is staged content?

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink: when you `git add` a file, you copy it from the work-tree into the index. Now the work-tree and index versions match, so the `--name-status <index> <work-tree>` part says nothing about it! Note that when you `git add -p` the file, you don't quite copy the work-tree version into the index: `git add -p` runs a Perl script that collects up the patches you want added, applies them to the index version, and writes that file directly into the index.

Comment: One other key insight, that many tutorials don't really mention (and Git itself obscures it with `--allow-empty`!) is that the index is almost never *empty*. It's usually quite full, of files that match either the current commit, or files that match the current work-tree. `--allow-empty` means "let me commit even if the index matches HEAD".